# Python + GStreamer: scale video to window

Tags: python, pygame, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm having some trouble rescaling video output of GStreamer to the dimension of the window the video is displayed in (retaining aspect ratio of the video). The problem is that I first need to preroll the video to be able to determine its dimensions by retrieving the negotiated caps, and then calculate the dimensions it needs to be displayed in to fit the window. Once I have prerolled the video and got the dimension caps, I cannot change the video's dimension anymore. Setting the new caps still results in the video being output in its original size. What must I do to solve this?

Just to be complete. In the current implementation I cannot render to an OpenGL texture which would have easily solved this problem because you could simply render output to the texture and scale it to fit the screen. I have to draw the output on a pygame surface, which needs to have the correct dimensions. pygame does offer functionality to scale its surfaces, but I think such an implementation (as I have now) is slower than retrieving the frames in their correct size directly from GStreamer (am I right?)

This is my code for loading and displaying the video (I omitted the main loop stuff):

```
def calcScaledRes(self, screen_res, image_res):
    """Calculate image size so it fits the screen
    Args
        screen_res (tuple)   -  Display window size/Resolution
        image_res (tuple)    -  Image width and height

    Returns
        tuple - width and height of image scaled to window/screen
    """
    rs = screen_res[0]/float(screen_res[1])
    ri = image_res[0]/float(image_res[1])

    if rs > ri:
        return (int(image_res[0] * screen_res[1]/image_res[1]), screen_res[1])
    else:
        return (screen_res[0], int(image_res[1]*screen_res[0]/image_res[0]))

def load(self, vfile):
    """
    Loads a videofile and makes it ready for playback

    Arguments:
    vfile -- the uri to the file to be played
    """
    # Info required for color space conversion (YUV->RGB)
    # masks are necessary for correct display on unix systems
    _VIDEO_CAPS = ','.join([
        'video/x-raw-rgb',
        'red_mask=(int)0xff0000',
        'green_mask=(int)0x00ff00',
        'blue_mask=(int)0x0000ff'
    ])

    self.caps = gst.Caps(_VIDEO_CAPS)

    # Create videoplayer and load URI
    self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")        
    self.player.set_property("uri", vfile)

    # Enable deinterlacing of video if necessary
    self.player.props.flags |= (1 << 9)     

    # Reroute frame output to Python
    self._videosink = gst.element_factory_make('appsink', 'videosink')      
    self._videosink.set_property('caps', self.caps)
    self._videosink.set_property('async', True)
    self._videosink.set_property('drop', True)
    self._videosink.set_property('emit-signals', True)
    self._videosink.connect('new-buffer', self.__handle_videoframe)     
    self.player.set_property('video-sink', self._videosink)

    # Preroll movie to get dimension data
    self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PAUSED)

    # If movie is loaded correctly, info about the clip should be available
    if self.player.get_state(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)[0] == gst.STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS:
        pads = self._videosink.pads()           
        for pad in pads:            
            caps = pad.get_negotiated_caps()[0]
            self.vidsize = caps['width'], caps['height']
        else:
            raise exceptions.runtime_error("Failed to retrieve video size")

# Calculate size of video when fit to screen
    self.scaledVideoSize = self.calcScaledRes((self.screen_width,self.screen_height), self.vidsize) 
# Calculate the top left corner of the video (to later center it vertically on screen)  
    self.vidPos = ((self.screen_width - self.scaledVideoSize [0]) / 2, (self.screen_height - self.scaledVideoSize [1]) / 2)

    # Add width and height info to video caps and reload caps
    _VIDEO_CAPS += ", width={0}, heigh={1}".format(self.scaledVideoSize[0], self.scaledVideoSize[1])
    self.caps = gst.Caps(_VIDEO_CAPS)
    self._videosink.set_property('caps', self.caps)  #??? not working, video still displayed in original size

def __handle_videoframe(self, appsink):
    """
    Callback method for handling a video frame

    Arguments:
    appsink -- the sink to which gst supplies the frame (not used)
    """     
    buffer = self._videosink.emit('pull-buffer')        

    img = pygame.image.frombuffer(buffer.data, self.vidsize, "RGB")

    # Upscale image to new surfuace if presented fullscreen
    # Create the surface if it doesn't exist yet and keep rendering to this surface
    # for future frames (should be faster)

    if not hasattr(self,"destSurf"):                
        self.destSurf = pygame.transform.scale(img, self.destsize)
    else:
        pygame.transform.scale(img, self.destsize, self.destSurf)
    self.screen.blit(self.destSurf, self.vidPos)

    # Swap the buffers
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Increase frame counter
    self.frameNo += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your issue was (has it is very long time since you asked this question) that you never hooked up the bus to watch for messages that were emitted.
The code for this is usually something like this:

```
    def some_function(self):
    #code defining Gplayer (the pipeline)
    #
    # here
        Gplayer.set_property('flags', self.GST_VIDEO|self.GST_AUDIO|self.GST_TEXT|self.GST_SOFT_VOLUME|self.GST_DEINTERLACE)
    # more code
    #
    # finally
        # Create the bus to listen for messages
        bus = Gplayer.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
        bus.connect('message', self.OnBusMessage)
        bus.connect('sync-message::element', self.OnSyncMessage)
#   Listen for gstreamer bus messages
    def OnBusMessage(self, bus, message):
        t = message.type
        if t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            pass
        elif t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
            print ("End of Audio")
        return True

    def OnSyncMessage(self, bus, msg):
        if msg.get_structure() is None:
            return True
        if message_name == 'prepare-window-handle':
            imagesink = msg.src
            imagesink.set_property('force-aspect-ratio', True)
            imagesink.set_window_handle(self.panel1.GetHandle())
```

The key bit for your issue is setting up a call back for the sync-message and in that call-back, setting the property `force-aspect-ratio` to True.
This property ensures that the video fits the window it is being displayed in at all times.

Note the self.panel1.GetHandle() function names the panel in which you are displaying the video.

I appreciate that you will have moved on but hopefully this will help someone else trawling through the archives.